# Qt QString::toDouble() returns int 0

Tags: c++, qt, type-conversion

I'm reading from an xml file and trying to parse the data to a double. It is reading the data and displays the appropriate string in the application output but wont convert from string to double. This is the section of code doing the conversion.

```
if ( !(imgDur = QString ( xmlReader->readElementText() ).toDouble()) ){
        imgDur = 10;
}
```

this returns the number 0. I get zero errors and the code compiles. Why wont this work? Thank you for you time.

The entire loop that reads the XML file

```
//Parse the XML until we reach end of it
    while(!xmlReader->atEnd() && !xmlReader->hasError()) {
            // Read next element
            QXmlStreamReader::TokenType token = xmlReader->readNext();
            //If token is just StartDocument - go to next
            if(token == QXmlStreamReader::StartDocument) {
                    continue;
            }
            //If token is StartElement - read it
            if(token == QXmlStreamReader::StartElement) {

                    if(xmlReader->name() == "time_delay") {
                        qWarning() << xmlReader->readElementText(); // OUTPUTS 15

                        if ( !(imgDur = QString (xmlReader->readElementText()).toDouble()  ) ){
                            qWarning() << "AS AN DOUBLE" << imgDur;  // OUTPUTS 0
                            imgDur = 10;
                        }

                    }

                    if(xmlReader->name() == "value") {
                        qWarning() << xmlReader->readElementText(); // OUTPUTS 8
                    }

            }
    }
```

Comment: What type is imgDur? Also you wrote you want to convert to double, so why are you using toFloat?

Comment: imgDur is a double. sry typo, i fixed it

Comment: What is the string? xmlReader->readElementText() could be returning anything as far as I know. Also, what do you mean by 'this returns the number 0'? There isn't a return statement anywhere there.

Comment: The string is the number 15. after this call it sets imgDur = 0; if I don't overwrite it.

Comment: `!(imgDur = ...)` will evaluate to `false` for `imgDur` non-zero. Maybe you meant `imgDur != ...`?

Comment: Your string is definitely not "15". That would convert to be `if(!(imgDur = 15.0)){imgDur = 10;}` which is just `imgDur = 15.0`.

Comment: yes it is. I made the XML file.

Comment: `qDebug("%f", QString("15").toDouble());` Output: `15.000000`
Whatever readElementText is giving you, it's not "15". The QString::toDouble conversion is probably failing due to getting an invalid string. It will return zero in that case.

Comment: qWarning() << xmlReader->readElementText(); outputs 15

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because there was a mistake in it. 
You have something very odd going on in your code if you get 0.0 for  QString("15").toDouble(). I have no further ideas, so all I can do is wish you good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem of your code was this `qWarning() << xmlReader->readElementText(); // OUTPUTS 15` line. `QXmlReader::readElementText()` moves xmlReader pointer to the end of the text node, so the `readNext()` will return `EndElement` of `A` instead of `QXmlStreamReader::Characters` token. So basicly `readElementText` does something like that (note that in the real implementation it is a lot more complicated, as it checks default behaviour, sets QXmlStreamReader internal data/status/token etc):

```
QString retval;
if(xmlReader->readNext() == QXmlStreamReader::Characters)
{
    retval = xmlReader->text().toString();
    xmlReader->readNext();
}
return retval;
```

So basicly second `xmlReader->readElementText();` will always return empty QString, as the current token is not `QXmlStreamReader::StartElement` anymore

Comment: Thank you for your help. I thought I had commented out that line in the passed but I guess not. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

First of all,we'll assume imgDur is a float. Then change your if statement to

`QString tempText = xmlReader->readElementText();`

`if (imgDur != tempText.toDouble()) {`

There was two problems, your conditional was a truth statement and you redundantly converted a QString to a QString.

Comment: error: '((MainWindow*)this)->MainWindow::xmlReader->QXmlStreamReader::readElementText' does not have class type              This is the error is produces with your changes.

Comment: try again, i forgot parentheses

Comment: I got "error: conversion from 'float' to 'QChar' is ambiguous" this time

Comment: Sure I've Updated  the original question

Answer (score 1):

You mention in the comments for the question that the number contained in the string that you're trying to convert is 15. Is it always going to be 15? If so, you should use `QString::toInt` instead, along with an integer type to store the return value of that function in.

If it's more dynamic, you may be better off leveraging the `bool*` parameter for toDouble and change your code to the following:

```
bool ok = false;
imgDur = xmlReader->readElementText().toDouble(&ok);
if (!ok) {
    imgDur = xmlReader->readElementText().toInt(&ok);
    if (!ok) {
        imgDur = 10.0;
    }
}
```